# Start counting from 1 when new value identified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a column that will start the count from 1 every time it finds a different value.

Here is an example of my table:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#myTable') is not null drop table #myTable
create table #myTable (dates int, flag char)

insert into #myTable values('20181031','V')
insert into #myTable values('20181130','V')
insert into #myTable values('20181231','V')
insert into #myTable values('20190131','F')
insert into #myTable values('20190228','F')
insert into #myTable values('20190331','F')
insert into #myTable values('20190430','F')
insert into #myTable values('20190531','V')
insert into #myTable values('20190630','V')
insert into #myTable values('20190731','V')

select *
from #myTable
order by 1

dates     flag
20181031    V
20181130    V
20181231    V
20190131    F
20190228    F
20190331    F
20190430    F
20190531    V
20190630    V
20190731    V
```

I need the output to look as follows:

```
dates      flag cnt
20181031    V   1
20181130    V   2
20181231    V   3
20190131    F   1
20190228    F   2
20190331    F   3
20190430    F   4
20190531    V   1
20190630    V   2
20190731    V   3
```

I have tried using variations of `row_number()` with sub-queries, but I could not get it to start counting again when it hits the second set of Vs.
I looked at these two solutions, but I could not extrapolate it for my purpose:
[Counting rows until where clause condition is saatisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411310/counting-rows-until-where-clause-condition-is-saatisfied)

[Transact-SQL - number rows until condition met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518062/transact-sql-number-rows-until-condition-met)

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Thank you

Comment: You should post you actual attempt rather than just mention it.

Comment: @DaleK I've added evidence of research. Regarding accepting answers, I will need to look through them again, but usually I did not see an answer that worked for me.

Comment: If an answer doesn't work for you, you should comment as to how and why to the author can improve their answer.

Comment: @DaleK I usually do that, I'll take a look if some are still relevant. 
Does my question still need to be downvoted? I've updated it with additional information as you've asked.

Comment: You're assuming it was me... many people expect to see an actual attempt...

Comment: @DaleK apologies, I did assume it was you. I guess we can leave it at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  The simplest solution is to use a difference of row numbers to define the groups.  Then an additional row number for the column you want:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by flag, seqnum - seqnum_2 order by date) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by date) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by flag order by date) as seqnum_2
      from #mytable t
     ) t
order by date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df16a50f826eccf956d56f4c0a5451dd) is a db<>fiddle.